# Testing with Rspec3 controllers with belongs_to association using instance_double

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm new in testing and learning Rspec, and I can't git it working.

(I have read the book Effective testing with Rspec3, and many tutorials ...also pluralsight.com)

The situation is very simple. In a `Companies` controller I want to test de Create method, the `company` model `belongs_to user`, and is this the code:

I think the problem is when execute

in test: `expect(Company).to receive(:new).with(company_params)`

or in controller: `@company.user=helpers.user`

Controller:

```
class CompaniesController < SessionsController

  def create
    @company=Company.new(company_params)     
    @company.user=helpers.user

    if @company.save()
      redirect_to companies_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

and Rspec:

```
RSpec.describe CompaniesController, type: :controller do

    let(:user) { instance_double(User) }

    before do
      allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationHelper).to receive(:user){user}
      allow(controller).to receive(:authorize){true}
    end

    describe 'Authenticated user with companies' do

      let(:company_params) { {company:{name:"Albert",domain:"www.albert.com"}} }
      let(:company) { instance_double(Company) }

      before do
        allow(Company).to receive(:new){company} 
      end

      describe 'POST #create' do
        context "with valid data" do

          before { allow(company).to receive(:save){true} }

          it "redirects to companies_path" do

            expect(Company).to receive(:new).with(company_params)
            expect(company).to receive(:user=).with(user)

            post :create, params:{company: company_params}
            expect(response).to redirect_to(companies_path)

          end
```

My intention is very simple: Use instance_double to mock (or stub) @company, and Company.new, using instance double...to test the create action, and simulate the "save()" returning true...etc

I do not know if I explain myself very well, but given the `create` action of controlloer , **how to test using mocks ans stubs, instance_double?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me explain what we need to test here

```
   def create
     @company=Company.new(company_params)     
     @company.user=helpers.user

     if @company.save()
       redirect_to companies_path
     else
       render :edit
     end 
   end
```

We are testing `create` action of a controller. First let us see what this action does? It's just takes `comapany_params` as input and create a company record in database.

Testing also goes like the same, we need to just pass the input that action required, and need to check whether it's creating record in database or not.

```
RSpec.describe CompaniesController, type: :controller do

    let(:user) { instance_double(User) }

   before do
    # all your authentication stubing goes here
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationHelper).to receive(:user){user}
    allow(controller).to receive(:authorize){true}
  end


  describe 'POST#create' do
    context 'with valid attributes' do
      before do
        post :create, { company:{ name:"Albert", domain:"www.albert.com"} }
      end

      it 'responds with success' do
        expect(response.status).to eq(302)
      end

      it 'creates company' do
        company = Company.find_by(name: "Albert")

        expect(assigns(:company)).to eq(company)
        expect(response).to redirect_to(companies_path())
      end
    end

    context 'with invalid attributes' do
      before do
        post :create, { company:{ name:"", domain:""} }
      end

      it 'renders new template' do
        expect(response).to render_template(:edit)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

No need to sub anything here. As per my knowledge, Only when we use any `lib classes` / `background jobs` / `third party libraries` code inside action then we need to stub those code. Because for all those, we will write specs separately. So no need to test again here that's why we'll do stubing.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will keep it in mind for future tests. Anyway following a Pluralsight course, I have seen how to stub all methods in a Create method, but is not an Activerecord, just simple objects, and I would like to know how to stub, the `@company.user=` and ` xxx=Company.new(company_params)`... with `allow` and `expect`...Is it possible to stub this associations? How should be my code for working without crash? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Narsimha Reddy, I have better ideas about how to test.
Eventhough, if I want to stub

```
 @company=Company.new(company_params)     
 @company.user=helpers.user
 if @company.save()
```

For testing only de `create`'s response , the solution was in a good use of parameters, and allowing `allow(company).to receive(:user=)` for the belongs_to association

```
  let(:company_params) {{company:{name:"Albert",domain:"www.albert.com"}}}
  let(:ac_company_params) {ActionController::Parameters.new(company_params).require(:company).permit!}

  let(:company) { instance_double(Company) }

  before do
    allow(Company).to receive(:new){company} 
    allow(company).to receive(:user=)
    allow(company).to receive(:save){true}
  end

  it "redirects to companies_path" do
    expect(Company).to receive(:new).with(ac_company_params)
    expect(company).to receive(:user=).with(user)

    post :create, params: company_params
    expect(response).to redirect_to(companies_path)
  end
```